# insert data to bigquery from gsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I would like to upload data to a table in bigquery from gsheet, I mean I want to upload the data with code and not with add on, because it will be scheduled later on.
Is there any code example that I can use for that for both ways (append and truncate)?
I have a 2 columns data that I want to load.
The columns are:

```
name    lastName    
josh    big
john    troble
```

May be some code using the following function

```
BigQuery.Jobs.insert(resource, projectId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looker is great on top of BigQuery and provides a very easy interface for embedding query results in google sheets (as well as excel).

http://www.looker.com/docs/sharing-and-publishing/publishing-looks-with-public-urls

- note, I work at (and on) Looker, but I also love BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial showing how to use Apps Script within a Google Spreadsheet to: (1) run a query and extract the results and put them into the spreadsheet, and (2) run a load job to import a file from Google Cloud Storage:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

Since that tutorial was written, BigQuery now supports inserting table rows directly through the tabledata.insertAll method:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll

If you want to upload some rows from a Google Spreadsheet into a BigQuery table, it looks like you can use Apps Script to insert the rows directly to BigQuery.

Another approach that should work: you can use Apps Script to create a file in Google Cloud Storage, then you can use example #2 from the first link above to load the data. The Google Cloud Storage API is accessible through Apps Script, so this should be possible. Here's a post showing how one user accomplished this step: http://ctrlq.org/code/20074-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check **Google BigQuery API in Apps Script**
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

Upload Job is to be used after you get data from gsheet

> BigQuery.Jobs.insert